# Is the way my class inherits list class methods pythonicly correct?

Tags: python, python-2.7

A little example will help clarify my question:

I define two classes: Security and Universe which I would like to behave as a list of Secutity objects.

Here is my example code:

```
class Security(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

class Universe(object):
    def __init__(self, securities):
        self.securities = securities

s1 = Security('name1')
s2 = Security('name2')
u = Universe([s1, s2])
```

I would like my Universe Class to be able to use usual list features such as enumerate(), len(), __getitem__()... :

```
enumerate(u)
len(u)
u[0]
```

So I defined my Class as:

```
class Universe(list, object):
    def __init__(self, securities):
        super(Universe, self).__init__(iter(securities))
        self.securities = securities
```

It seems to work, but is it the appropriate pythonic way to do it ?

[EDIT]

The above solution does not work as I wish when I subset the list:

```
>>> s1 = Security('name1')
>>> s2 = Security('name2')
>>> s3 = Security('name3')
>>> u = Universe([s1, s2, s3])
>>> sub_u = u[0:2]
>>> type(u)
<class '__main__.Universe'>
>>> type(sub_u)
<type 'list'>
```

I would like my variable sub_u to remain of type Universe.

Comment: Yes, `list.__getitem__` does not return a `self.__class__` instance, but a `list` instance. And you will find the same with, e.g., `u1 + u2`. So, you need to wrap any methods you care about. (Exactly how you do that depends on whether you're using inheritance, explicit delegation, `__getattr__` delegation, etc., but it should be pretty obvious in each case.)

Comment: @Sam: That's part of what I was referring to in my answer.  The methods of `list` that you inherit don't interact with your class.

Answer (score 6):

You don't have to actually be a `list` to use those features. That's the whole point of duck typing. Anything that defines `__getitem__(self, i)` automatically handles `x[i]`, `for i in x`, `iter(x)`, `enumerate(x)`, and various other things. Also define `__len__(self)` and `len(x)`, `list(x)`, etc. also work. Or you can define `__iter__` instead of `__getitem__`. Or both. It depends on exactly how `list`-y you want to be.

The documentation on Python's [special methods](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-names) explains what each one is for, and organizes them pretty nicely.

For example:

```
class FakeList(object):
    def __getitem__(self, i):
        return -i
fl = FakeList()
print(fl[20])
for i, e in enumerate(fl):
    print(i)
    if e < -2: break
```

No `list` in sight.

If you actually have a `real` list and want to represent its data as your own, there are two ways to do that: delegation, and inheritance. Both work, and both are appropriate in different cases.

If your object really *is* a `list` plus some extra stuff, use inheritance. If you find yourself stepping on the base class's behavior, you may want to switch to delegation anyway, but at least start with inheritance. This is easy:

```
class Universe(list): # don't add object also, just list
    def __init__(self, securities):
        super(Universe, self).__init__(iter(securities))
        # don't also store `securities`--you already have `self`!
```

You may also want to override [`__new__`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__), which allows you to get the `iter(securities)` into the `list` at creation time rather than initialization time, but this doesn't usually matter for a `list`. (It's more important for immutable types like `str`.)

If the fact that your object *owns* a list rather than *being* one is inherent in its design, use delegation.

The simplest way to delegate is explicitly. Define the exact same methods you'd define to fake being a `list`, and make them all just forward to the `list` you own:

```
class Universe(object):
    def __init__(self, securities):
        self.securities = list(securities)
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return self.securities[index] # or .__getitem__[index] if you prefer
    # ... etc.
```

You can also do delegation through [`__getattr__`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattr__):

```
class Universe(object):
    def __init__(self, securities):
        self.securities = list(securities)
    # no __getitem__, __len__, etc.
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        if name in ('__getitem__', '__len__',
                    # and so on
                   ):
            return getattr(self.securities, name)
        raise AttributeError("'{}' object has no attribute '{}'"
                             .format(self.__class__.__name__), name)
```

---

Note that many of `list`'s methods will return a new `list`. If you want them to return a new `Universe` instead, you need to wrap those methods. But keep in mind that some of those methods are binary operators—for example, should `a + b` return a `Universe` only if `a` is one, or only if both are, or if either are?

Also, `__getitem__` is a little tricky, because they can return either a `list` or a single object, and you only want to wrap the former in a `Universe`. You can do that by checking the return value for `isinstance(ret, list)`, or by checking the index for `isinstance(index, slice)`; which one is appropriate depends on whether you can have `list`s as element of a `Universe`, and whether they should be treated as a `list` or as a `Universe` when extracted. Plus, if you're using inheritance, in Python 2, you also need to wrap the deprecated `__getslice__` and friends, because `list` does support them (although `__getslice__` always returns a sub-list, not an element, so it's pretty easy).

Once you decide those things, the implementations are easy, if a bit tedious. Here are examples for all three versions, using `__getitem__` because it's tricky, and the one you asked about in a comment. I'll show a way to use generic helpers for wrapping, even though in this case you may only need it for one method, so it may be overkill.

Inheritance:

```
class Universe(list): # don't add object also, just list
    @classmethod
    def _wrap_if_needed(cls, value):
        if isinstance(value, list):
            return cls(value)
        else:
            return value
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        ret = super(Universe, self).__getitem__(index)
        return _wrap_if_needed(ret)
```

Explicit delegation:

```
class Universe(object):
    # same _wrap_if_needed
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        ret = self.securities.__getitem__(index)
        return self._wrap_if_needed(ret)
```

Dynamic delegation:

```
class Universe(object):
    # same _wrap_if_needed
    @classmethod
    def _wrap_func(cls, func):
        @functools.wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            return cls._wrap_if_needed(func(*args, **kwargs))
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        if name in ('__getitem__'):
            return self._wrap_func(getattr(self.securities, name))
        elif name in ('__len__',
                      # and so on
                      ):
            return getattr(self.securities, name)
        raise AttributeError("'{}' object has no attribute '{}'"
                             .format(self.__class__.__name__), name)
```

As I said, this may be overkill in this case, especially for the `__getattr__` version. If you just want to override one method, like `__getitem__`, and delegate everything else, you can always define `__getitem__` explicitly, and let `__getattr__` handle everything else.

If you find yourself doing this kind of wrapping a lot, you can write a function that generates wrapper classes, or a class decorator that lets you write skeleton wrappers and fills in the details, etc. Because the details depend on your use case (all those issues I mentioned above that can go one way or the other), there's no one-size-fits-all library that just magically does what you want, but there are a number of recipes on ActiveState that show more complete details—and there are even a few wrappers in the standard library source.

Comment: @abarnet : just to make sure I understood correctly and looking at my EDIT example, I have to go with delegation and write my own __getitem__() function if I want u[0:2] to return a Universe object ?

Comment: @Sam: Well, no, you _could_ still use inheritance, you just have to override `__getitem__` to call `super` and wrap the result, just as with delegation you'd call the contained object and wrap the result. Also, if you use inheritance, you need to wrap `__getslice__` as well. I've updated the answer to show examples.

Answer (score 5):

That is a reasonable way to do it, although you don't need to inherit from both `list` and `object`.  `list` alone is enough.  Also, if your class is a list, you don't need to store `self.securities`; it will be stored as the contents of the list.

However, depending on what you want to use your class for, you may find it easier to define a class that stores a list internally (as you were storing `self.securities`), and then define methods on your class that (sometimes) pass through to the methods of this stored list, instead of inheriting from `list`.  The Python builtin types don't define a rigorous interface in terms of which methods depend on which other ones (e.g., whether `append` depends on `insert`), so you can run into confusing behavior if you try to do any nontrivial manipulations of the contents of your list-class.

Edit: As you discovered, any operation that returns a new list falls into this category.  If you subclass `list` without overriding its methods, then you call methods on your object (explicitly or implicitly), the underlying `list` methods will be called.  These methods are hardcoded to return a plain Python list and do not check what the actual class of the object is, so they will return a plain Python list.

Comment: I'm pretty sure none of the "public" methods depend on each other. (And if they do, they depend on the built-in implementation, not your overrides, so it doesn't matter.)

Comment: @abarnert: That's what's confusing, though.  Some people (reasonably) expect to be able to override one method and have it affect the behavior of others that conceptually might depend on it.

Comment: OK, I understand what you're saying, and agree. I thought you were giving the same answer that people usually give with C++ (where it actually _is_ complicated, but also is thoroughly documented), rather than Python (where it's very simple, but you have to figure that out for yourself the first time).

Comment: @BrenBarn , thanks for your answer. Regarding at the EDIT example, do you think I can use inheritance and and get u[0:2] to return a Universe instead of a class without having to redefine myself __getitem__() ?

Comment: @Sam: No, you cannot.  If you inherit from `list`, the list methods will be used, and they are hardcoded to return a plain list.

Comment: @Sam: It's worth noting that you don't have to redefine `__getitem__` in the sense that you have to implement it yourself from scratch; you can just call `super` and wrap the result. (Also, for `u[0:2]`, if `u` is a `list` subclass, it's actually calling `__getslice__` in Python 2.) See my answer for the gory details.